# storage Is a directory

Tags: php, laravel

```
$path = 'uploads/multi/' . Auth::user()->id;   
Storage::disk('local')->put($path,$fl);
почему такая ошибка 

file_put_contents(/home/e/extremje/china/china/storage/app/uploads/multi/1): failed to open stream: Is a directory
```

Comment: за что минус то?

Comment: Потому что это не вопрос, а кусок неотформатированного текста, в котором мало кому захочется разбираться.

Comment: вы откройте документацию, ну. Вот же пример есть даже - `Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');` Вы видите, что файл имеет имя и расширение? А перед ним пишите путь, какой нужно. Или создайте свой диск.

Comment: Storage::disk('public')->put($path.'/'.$fl, 'Contents'); когда сохраняю размер файлы не 26кб а 6 байт и фото не открывает, почему?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что созданный вами $path, указывает на директорию, а писать в неё Вы пытаетесь, как в файл

Comment: а contents для чего? вот этого я не понимаю

Comment: @Pupsik функция `file_put_contents` пишет В ФАЙЛ. А ссылка сгенерирована на директорию.